# Update row in mysql from dropdown menu

Tags: php, mysql

I have table which is populated from mysql. One of the rows is `status` which is 0 by default and is have dropdown menu where I can choose `1` or `2`. Then there is button `update` which should update that row in the table. The problem is that didn't update.

this is the table form

```
if(isset($_GET['rest_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['rest_id'])){
        $rest_id = $_GET['rest_id'];

        $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM reservation
                      WHERE table_res_id = $rest_id 
                      ORDER BY `DateTime` DESC ");

                echo "</p>";

                // display data in table

                echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered responsive">';
                echo "<thead>";
                echo '<tr>      
                        <th>Name</th> 
                        <th>Comment</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th></th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>';
                echo '<div class="row">';
                echo '<div class="box col-md-12">';
                echo '<div class="box-content">';
                echo "<tbody>";
                // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
                while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
                {

                    echo '<tr>';                        
                    echo '<td>' . $query['name'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $query['comment'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>                      
                    <div class="btn-group">
                    <select>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><option> Status:'. $query['status'] .' 
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </option></li>
                    <li><option>1</option></li>
                    <li><option>2</option></li>
                        </ul>
                </select>                    
                </div>
                           </td>';
                            echo '<td>
                        <a  class="btn btn-info" href="users/Confirm.php?id=' . $query['id'] . '">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit icon-white"></i>
                        Change status</a></td>';

                    echo "</tr>";
```

This is `confirm.php`

```
session_start();
include '../misc/db.inc.php';
ob_start();
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{

$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE id=$id" or die(mysqli_error($con));
$res = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE reservation SET status = ? LIMIT 1"))

{
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$res['status');
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
else
{
    echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
}
$con->close();
```

Comment: Set a string or die? That makes no sense. Execute a string or die? Now, that makes sense!!

Comment: is_numeric() is no proper way to protect you from sql injection. Ask Sony.

Comment: my suggestion to you is that just submit the form nomrally, so that form inputs, including your select dropdown will be included in the request, then make you process on PHP

Comment: @Strawberry I don't get what you mean? Ghost are you suggest to send to db again same information?

Comment: This is gibberish: `$query = "SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE id=$id" or die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: You mean to remove that `die`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code your are sending database value again to confirm.php not the user selected value.
For this, assign name to  like  ..and instead of anchor click use form submission.. it will work.

Another solution.
You can call onchange event on  where javascript function will get call and will update selected value in database via Ajax..Hope this logic will help you

Answer (score 1):

According to our previous comments:

Make a button `<input type="button" onclick="saveChange('.$id.')"/>`

Then set the function 'url' to `users/confirm.php`

and set the 'data' to the id..

```
    function saveChange(id){
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "users/confirm.php",
                data: 'id='+id
        });
    }
```

---

### Old

---

I suggest you use something like that:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(msg){}
        });
```

with `onchange=""` event, and at `save.php` you simply use an update method.

By the way

`$query = "SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE id=$id" or die(mysqli_error($con));
$res = mysqli_query($con, $query);`

was ment to be like:

`$query = "SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE id=$id";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: I didn't try with ajax or javascript because I have no idea about them yet. Where to put this?

Comment: Well in header between `<script></script>` with a function like so `saveChange()`

Comment: `saveChange()` on the button or? Because now button `change status` is pointing `id` and update the status field with the equal value like id.

Comment: Nono, you want the dropdown menu to save `onchange` right?

Comment: Yes, default value is `0`. I want when I change from dropdown to `1` or `2` and hit the `Change Status` button to update that in database table. Yes, I've fixed this after @Strawberry commented about it.

Comment: Oh sorry my missunderstanding then. Yes put it on the button with `saveChange('.$id.')` then set the `data` with it.

Comment: Nothing happen.. I've put this in `<script></script>` in `head` on button is `href="users/confirm.php?id=saveChange('.$id.')"`

Comment: Can't change button. First my `header.php` is included in this page and I don't know if will work that way. Second when I change button like you suggest is not clickable. And third in that way I think will update again status to ID.. I gues I will continue to try without ajax because I'm not familiar with it. Thank's for your help any way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66300/discussion-between-caddaile-and-goro).